# Highcharts data label getting cut off

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I'm having a small problem with Highcharts, I've got everything looking how I want it to but I can't find how to force the datalables to stay within the confines of the parent div.

I've attached a basic example, as you can see the data labels are cut off, any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/FCHhS/3/

Answer (score 6):

You can pull in or push out the labels by controlling the [**distance**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) of the `dataLabels`.  In the following [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/FCHhS/5/) I set the distance to -1 which pulls the labels in.